# When I try to move my Object Mesh certain points are locked in place, while the rest just stretches

Tags: edit-mode

So I'm making a replication of an iron man helmet. I've been extending my mesh and moving the vertices just fine, but out of nowhere whenever I try to move one it's like another object is layered in front of mine, and it only grabs that vert. If I grab all the faces on my object and go to move it, parts of it stretch out while others stay in place instead of moving as one unit. I have no idea what button I pressed to cause this, and I don't have proportional editing on. [image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I uploaded it I'm not sure if you can see it or how I share it if I need to?

Comment: you need to share the link it gives you  ;)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=wYreEYEy" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/wYreEYEy/)

Answer (score 1):

You have overlapping faces, to fix that select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*. Also, as you've enabled the *Clipping* option of the *Mirror* modifier, if you try to move the vertices that are at the mirror axis, they will stick to it.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!